# How to Print Results of Method in toString Method in the Same Class?

Tags: java, methods, tostring

I have this method in my class called `Detective`:

```
  public boolean check (String line)
    {
        // Separte the information into three categories
        String[] categories = line.split("; ");
        String[] info;

        // Get the suspect's information
        info = categories[0].split(", ");
        suspect = new Person(info[0].charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(info[1]), Double.parseDouble(info[2]));

       Person person = new Person();
       //System.out.println(theOracle.checkPerson(suspect));
       if (theOracle.checkPerson(suspect) == 0){

           String st = null;
        categories[0] = st;
           String str = "";
           if (info[0].charAt(0) == 'M')
               str += "Male, ";
           else if (info[0].charAt(0) == 'F')
               str += "Female, ";
           else
               str += "unknown, ";

           str += Integer.parseInt(info[1]) + "'s, ";
           str += Double.parseDouble(info[2]) +"m";
           System.out.println(str);
            }
       // Get the location
       info = categories[1].split(", ");
       suspectLocation = new Location(Double.parseDouble(info[0]), Double.parseDouble(info[1]));
       //System.out.println(theOracle.checkLocation(suspectLocation));

       // Get the time
       info = categories[2].split(":");
       suspectTime = new Time(Integer.parseInt(info[0]), Integer.parseInt(info[1]));

        return false;
    }
```

and the toString method also in the same class:

```
public String toString()
{
    String str = "";
    str = "Person: " +   "/n";
    return str;
}
```

How can I get the results of what gets printed in the check method to print in the toString method before `/n`? I have attempted to copy what is in my check method and put it in the toString method but it just prints a location @ hash code. Is there any way to simply copy the string result of the check method for printing purposes into the toString?

Basically what I'm asking is how can I simply take the str that is output in the check method and print it instead in my toString method.

Comment: If you want to print out the `Person` object info, implement the `toString()` method in the `Person` class.

Comment: This is already implemented in the person class `    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "";
        if (gender == 'F')
            str += "female, ";
        else if (gender == 'M')
            str += "male, ";
        else
            str += "unknown, ";
            
        str += ageRange + "'s, ";
        str += height +"m";
        
        return str;
    }`

Comment: Now if I create a new person object in the toString in detective and print that it prints exactly what the above ^^ says, when it needs to print the M --> male conversion etc.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Comments are hard to fomat and read.

Comment: If you want to keep the `str` value beyond its method, make it a member rather than a local variable. Note that then your `toString` depends on `check` being called first, which is odd, to say the least, since `toString` should always give you usable output, no matter what state the object is in.

Comment: @Robert yes, but I think it would be impossible to print something in the toString since it is generating hascode when I attempt to do so. Overriding is not an option.

Comment: @Robert you are right, it will need to be useable, but I think it is impossible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take out `str` variable at instance level, rather than declaring it in `check` method.

now your `toString` method:

```
public String toString()
{
    return str;
}
```

ensure to call `check` before your application calls `toString`, one way to do this is by calling the `check` method from the `Detective` constructor.

Comment: can't do this. str will be undeclared.

Comment: what does this mean 'undeclared'. 
String str = ""; //at instance level

Comment: you mean to do `Private String str;`

Comment: Yes I can do that, but it will output as null.

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer, you need to make sure to call check before calling toString, may be from Constructor?

Comment: If not, you may need to think about your design, the purpose of toString...

Answer (score 0):

you need to change method `check()` to return a string

```
public Strin gcheck (String line){...
```

remove or keep the `print` call in check():

```
System.out.println(str);
```

and instead of `return false;` change it to `return str;`

now in `toString()` make a call to `check()` and concatenate the result.

```
public String toString()
{
    String str = "";
    str = "Person: " +  check() + "/n";
    return str;
}
```